# GitLab 502 Bad Gateway Error

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I'm trying to [install GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu) on an Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS server running from an [Antsle Nano](https://go.antsle.com/antsle-nano/) device. The server already had Nginx, PostgreSQL, and Postfix installed as a part of [iRedMail](https://www.iredmail.org/), so I'm working on setting GitLab up to use those resources. All the existing sites on my Nginx server still appear to be working normally (*e.g, `webmail.mydomain.com`, `wiki.mydomain.com` - a [Wiki.Js](https://js.wiki/) installation - and `www.mydomain.com`*), but when I try to access my GitLab install through the browser (*`gitlab.mydomain.com`*), I get a **`502 Bad Gateway`** response.

I've followed the instructions for [using a non-bundled web server](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server) and disabled the bundled Nginx server (and the bundled PostgreSQL server as well) in the `gitlab.rb`. Then I added the `server` information to the Nginx `sites-enabled` configuration file according to the [GitLab recipe](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/-/blob/master/web-server/nginx/gitlab-omnibus-ssl-nginx.conf). I installed an SSL certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) for that specific subdomain that's showing to be valid when I go to the site.

I'm sure I'm just "overlooking" something here, but I'll readily admit that I'm not terribly familiar with *nix environments in general or Nginx in particular. Here are the uncommented sections of my `gitlab.rb` file (*redacted*):

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.mydomain.com'

postgresql['enable'] = false

gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = 'postgresql'
gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = 'utf8'
gitlab_rails['db_username'] = 'USERNAME'
gitlab_rails['db_password'] = 'PASSWORD'
gitlab_rails['db_host'] = '127.0.0.1'
gitlab_rails['db_port'] = 5432

web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']

nginx['enable'] = false
nginx['ssl_prefer_server_ciphers'] = "off"
```

Everything else in the file is commented out.

For the sake of completeness, here are the `conf` settings for GitLab in my Nginx `sites-enabled` (*redacted*)

```
upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  # On GitLab versions before 13.5, the location is
  # `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket`. Change the following line
  # accordingly.
  server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on ssl;
    server_name gitlab.mydomain.com;
    server_tokens off;

    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

    # GitLab needs backwards compatible ciphers to retain compatibility with Java IDEs
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ## Individual nginx logs for this GitLab vhost
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 0;
        gzip off;

        ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
        ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /var/www/ssl/;
        allow all;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.mydomain.com/chain.pem;
}
```

The PostgreSQL appears to be set up correctly - I was able to run the `gitlab-rake gitlab:setup` and the `gitlabhq_production` database exists on that server with its various schemata and tables.

As I said, I'm probably simply doing something wrong, but I'm just not sure what. I thought about removing the `proxy` stuff from the `conf` since that's about all I can think of that could be causing the **`Bad Gateway`** response, but that would remove the `workhorse` part, which I *believe* is important. Otherwise, everything else seems pretty much essential there.

It's certainly possible that I need to tweak the `gitlab.rb` some more, but I've tried to look through there a few times for anything that looks promising without luck. If anyone has any insight into what I'm missing here, I'd be grateful.

### EDIT:

*additional information about my own troubleshooting*
I've tested the Nginx `conf` file and restarted that server:

```
nginx -t
systemctl reload nginx.service
systemctl restart nginx
```

I've run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` multiple times as I've made adjustments to the `gitlab.rb`. I just remembered that there have been some "issues" that have come up as a part of those which are probably at least partially to blame:

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout: ruby_block[authorize Grafana with GitLab] (monitoring::grafana line 101) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout: Command timed out after 600s:
Command exceeded allowed execution time, process terminated
```

followed by a lot of StackTrace information (*which I can provide if it will help*)

### EDIT #2:

Per comment, I tried to make sure that the GitLab service(s) are running:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl start
ok: run: alertmanager: (pid 29660) 51764s
ok: run: gitaly: (pid 26686) 58352s
ok: run: gitlab-exporter: (pid 3223) 46573s
ok: run: gitlab-kas: (pid 26650) 58367s
ok: run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 29598) 51780s
ok: run: logrotate: (pid 9914) 864s
ok: run: node-exporter: (pid 29608) 51779s
ok: run: prometheus: (pid 29626) 51776s
ok: run: puma: (pid 2698) 47257s
ok: run: redis: (pid 26145) 58729s
ok: run: redis-exporter: (pid 29619) 51777s
ok: run: sidekiq: (pid 2535) 47368s
```

As far as I can tell with my limited understanding, that looks like it should be "good-to-go", but I'm still getting the **`Bad Gateway`** response from my browsers. It doesn't show those services when I check `ls /etc/init.d`, but I *assume* that everything should be correct.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138181/discussion-on-question-by-g-hosa-phat-gitlab-502-bad-gateway-error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the diagnostics I had you do in chat, we discovered that:

1. The Gitlab socket is in fact running, confirmed with `find /var/opt/gitlab/ -type s` showing the socket existing.
2. NGINX does not have access to the intermediate directories of `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse` and `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/`.  Which was the core issue.  This was confirmed with output of `sudo -u www-data namei -l /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket` which showed that only `git` and `gitlab-www` had access, and the folder was not world-recurseable, which is needed for NGINX.

To fix *that* error, you need to make sure there's read/execute permissions on those directories.

```
sudo chmod o+rx /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/
```

The remaining issue you have is a Gitlab internal 502 - this indicates stuff is not fully loaded yet in GitLab.  Wait up to 20 minutes.  GitLab is *not* a small set of software/packages, so it has a lot that it has to start up before it can be used by a frontend.

If that ever freezes, restart Gitlab again with `sudo gitlab-ctl stop && sudo gitlab-ctl start` and then wait up to 20 minutes for the service to return.

---

Alternatively, consider a lighter git environment like [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/) if you have issues with Gitlab and resources on the system.  Gitea is less feature-rich than Gitlab, but if all you're doing is practicing your git-fu you don't need the full complicated and complete feature-set that Gitlab provides.  Gitea is not featureless, either, but it's got *less* components than GitLab does, which makes it an easier-to-deploy and easier-to-use environment if all you're doing is practicing with Git and having a GUI for your git repos.

(It also does not have a 4 vCPU and 4GB RAM *minimum requirements* 8GB RAM recommended like Gitlab does, and that's assuming you've got a dedicated system/VM for Gitlab)

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I ended up deleting/purging everything to do with GitLab on that server - I don't think the system was "beefy" enough for it - and installing Gitea instead. It seems to be running fine now and I have a platform where I can finally start teaching myself how to start using Git.

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat happy to assist either way, glad you settled on something :)